# The objects that have same name within different 'with.name_scope()" are different?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm making deep CNN layer, so need many variables similar.
When making layer, I want to make variable name simple as much as possible.

Is it okay to use same name within different 'tf.name_scope()' as following code? I'm so wonder whether 'earlier bias(variable) is overlapped by later bias when save model, and earlier bias is not saved'. In my opinion, guessing earlier bias and later bias are managed separately by each name_scope, but I'm not sure...

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
  with g.name_scope("CNN"):
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(20.0, name="c"), name="b")

  with g.name_scope("NN"):
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(30.0, name="c"), name="b")
```

Could you let me know the proper and exact concept of this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variable_scope/

your variable names are:

```
CNN/c:0
CNN/b:0
NN/c:0
NN/b:0
```

Comment: I read what you link, and one more question occur. I have a confusion between variable 'bias' and 'CNN/b:0'. As I understand, 'bias' is a variable in program which just save the value of 'CNN/b:0', and 'CNN/b:0' is tensor name in tensorflow graph. Is it right?